# Passing global javascript array to another function

Tags: javascript, arrays, global-variables

I have a small javascript which has a globally declared array. The values for that array are filled inside the function `foo()` as given below:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
 <script>
    var myArray = [];

  function foo() {
     var j = 5;
      for (var i = 0; i < j; i++) {
         myArray.push(i+1);
       }  
    }

  function bar() {
   alert(myArray);
   }

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I trying to access that array in another javascript function `bar()`, the values of array are null. How can I fix this?

Comment: call foo() before bar()

Comment: Not working @Harpreet Singh http://jsfiddle.net/U5L9w/

Comment: Its working. Do i need to show a screen shot of mine in a comment?

Comment: But the global variable should be accessible anywhere inside the script without calling the function right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have defined the function but never called it.

Try calling `foo()` and `bar()` like this

```
  var myArray = [];

function foo() {
   var j = 5;
    for (var i = 0; i < j; i++) {
       myArray.push(i+1);
     }  
  }

function bar() {
  alert(myArray);
 }

 foo();

 bar();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NavinKrishnan/W6jgh/)

Comment: @mpsbhat you're not understanding. simply defining a method/function wont execute, you need to call it. in your case see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NavinKrishnan/W6jgh/2/)

Comment: But the global variable should be accessible anywhere inside the script without calling the function right @Navin?

Comment: @mpsbhat yes, that's the reason you're getting `empty` array in `alert`, if not global then you'd get `myArray` is `undefined` error.

Comment: So once a global variable declared and if a value is assigned to it inside a function, then that value should present until the another value is assigned to it?

Comment: see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NavinKrishnan/W6jgh/3/) hope you'll understand now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to call bar() directly then.

```
<script>

  function foo(myArray) {

          var j = 5;

          for (var i = 0; i < j; i++) {

              myArray.push(i+1);

          }  

         return myArray;
  }

  function bar() 
  {
       alert(foo([]));
  }

  bar();  

// or

  alert(foo([]));

 </script>
```

Try to avoid as many global variables as you can,